# mmap's worst case memory usage when using MAP_PRIVATE vs MAP_SHARED

Tags: c++, memory, mmap

I haven't seen this explicitly anywhere so I just wanted to clarify. This is all in the context of a single threaded program: say we have a 10GB text file when we open with `mmap`, using the `MAP_PRIVATE` option. Initially of course, I should expect to see 0GB resident memory used. Now say I modify every character in the file. Will this then require 10GB in resident memory? And if not, why not?

Now what if we did the same thing but with `MAP_SHARED`, what should I expect the resident memory usage to look like?

Comment: Probably not. The file will be paged in and out. How much VM it uses depends on the rapidity and patter of access. MEM_PRIVATE and MEM_SHARED should not differ in this respect, apart from any sharing that takes place of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAP_SHARED` creates a mapping that is backed by the original file. Any changes to the data are written back to that file (assuming a read/write mapping).

`MAP_PRIVATE` creates a mapping that is backed by the original file *for reads only*. If you change bytes in the mapping, then the OS creates a new page that is occupies physical memory and is backed by swap (if any).

The impact on resident set size is not dependent on the mapping type: pages will be in your resident set if they're actively accessed (read or write). If the OS needs physical memory, then pages that are not actively accessed are dropped (if clean), or written to either the original file or swap (if dirty, and depending on mapping type).

Where the two types differ is in total commitment against physical memory and swap. A shared mapping doesn't increase this commitment, a private mapping does. If you don't have enough combined memory and swap to hold every page of the private mapping, and you write to every page, then you (or possibly some other process) will be killed by the out-of-memory daemon.

**Update:** what I wrote above applies to memory-mapped *files*. You can map an anonymous block (`MAP_ANONYMOUS`) with `MAP_SHARED`, in which case the memory is backed by swap, not a file.

Comment: That clarifies a lot, thanks! So does that mean `MAP_SHARED` doesn't have that same concern with swap+RAM not being big enough to store the file, because it can just write the dirty pages back to disk?

Comment: That's correct. Shared mappings are backed by the file. If the system needs RAM, it can write those pages to the file, not swap.

Comment: IMO, the uses for a private mapping are very few. Basically, cases where multiple processes need to start from the same "seed" state, but will make their own changes to the data.

Comment: So in theory, I could have a machine with no dedicated swap space only say, 1GB RAM and be able to read and write to a 100GB file if I use mmap with `MAP_SHARED`?

Comment: Yes, although with 1 GB of RAM you'll find that you're spending a lot of time in IO waits. It's really no different from opening (and updating) a 100 GB file when you have 32 GB of RAM and 32 GB of swap: the file is still larger than available committable memory.